Passing Matrices (larger arrays) between modules
I'm trying to have my design be more compartmentalized and separate each task into different modules/source files. I basically want to pass a matrix and a vector into a module I created where I'll do some operations on both before returning another vector. I should specify I'm using verilog and not systemverilog as well. I found this way of flattening arrays and passing them between modules:
module Testing(
\\inputs
);
reg signed [7:0] vector [0:8-1];    
wire [8*8-1:0] temp_mem1;
genvar i;
    generate for (i = 0; i < 8; i = i+1) begin
        assign temp_mem1[8*i +: 8] = vector[i];
    end endgenerate
endmodule

module mult(
input [8*8-1:0] input_vector1);

integer i;
  always @(posedge clk)begin
    for (i = 0; i < 8; i = i+1)begin
      vector[i] = input_vector1[8*i +: 8];
  end    
      end
endmodule

This works perfectly for 1D arrays. I'm trying to modify this to also allow passing matrices (2D arrays) in the same way but it's not working. The output just gives me a bunch of ZZ's, XX's, and some correct values:
module Testing#(
parameter N = 3
)(
    \\inputs
    );   
    wire [8*8*8-1:0] temp_mem3;
    reg signed [15:0] matrix [0:8-1][0:8-1]; 
    genvar q, w;
        generate
            for (q = 0; q < 8; q = q + 1) begin
                for (w = 0; w < 8; w = w + 1) begin
                    assign temp_mem3[8*q + w*8 +: 8] = matrix[q][w]; 
                end
            end
        endgenerate
    mult #(.N(3)) f2 (.clk(clk),.input_matrix(temp_mem3));
    endmodule

    module mult(
    input [8*8*8-1:0] input_matrix);
    reg signed [7:0] matrix [0:8-1][0:8-1]; 
    
    integer q, w;
        always @(posedge clk) begin
            for (q = 0; w < 8; q = q + 1) begin
                for (w = 0; w < 8; w = w + 1) begin
                    matrix[q][w] = input_matrix[8*q + w*8 +: 8];
                end
            end
        end
    endmodule

Any advice on how I could modify this to pass matrices between modules would be much appreciated.  For reference, I followed the method shown in this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16369698/how-to-pass-array-structure-between-two-verilog-modules

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

How could this have possibly worked? You never defined or declared your clock or any other inputs. You should be using nonblocking assignments to prevent races in your design.

The clock is implied, this code only includes what's needed to understand my issue. I got it to work and will consider adding unblocking assignments

Here is a complete code example showing how to declare module ports with multiple dimensions and connecting them together in a top-level module:
module mod1 (output reg [7:0] matrix [2][2]);
    initial begin
        for (int i=0; i<2; i++) begin
            for (int j=0; j<2; j++) begin
                matrix[i][j] = (i+1) * (j+1);
            end
        end
    end
endmodule

module mod2 (input [7:0] matrix [2][2]);
    initial begin
        #1;
        for (int i=0; i<2; i++) begin
            for (int j=0; j<2; j++) begin
                $display(matrix[i][j]);
            end
        end
    end
endmodule

module tb;
    wire [7:0] matrix [2][2];
    mod1 mod1 (.matrix(matrix));
    mod2 mod2 (.matrix(matrix));
endmodule

Simulation output:
  1
  2
  2
  4

These syntax features were introduced as part of SystemVerilog, which was released in 2005.  You may need to enable these features in your simulation tool.  Refer to IEEE Std 1800-2023, section 7.4 Packed and unpacked arrays

Thanks for the response. I forgot to specify that I'm actually using verilog instead of system verilog. Since all of my code is in verilog already, I've decided to stick with it instead of switching to systemverilog

@Samuel: You're welcome. Don't be afraid of SV.  It's just a name.  You don't need to "switch" to SV.  Besides, from the answer you posted, you already know the syntax is not supported by the old Verilog.  Give it a try.

Issue is resolved. I got it working by treating each matrix column as a separate array and recombining them back together in the new module.

Could you post your working example?
